# Error when installing AppFabric 1.1 on Server 2012 64bit

Tags: windows-server-2012, 64-bit, windows-server-2012-r2, appfabric

I am trying to install AppFabric 1.1 on 64bit Windows Server 2012 R2.

- All updates have been installed and updates are turned ON
- .NET Framework 4.0 is installed
- .NET Framework 3.5 is installed
- IIS is installed
- Windows Powershell 3.0 should already be included in Server 2012

I am getting the following error:

```
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  ===== Logging started: 2014-03-21 11:02:34+01:00 =====
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  File:             c:\6c4006b0b3f6dee1bf616f1967\setup.exe
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  InternalName:     Setup.exe
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  OriginalFilename: Setup.exe
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  FileVersion:      1.1.2106.32
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  FileDescription:  Setup.exe
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  Product:          Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server AppFabric
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  ProductVersion:   1.1.2106.32
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  Debug:            False
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  Patched:          False
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  PreRelease:       False
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  PrivateBuild:     False
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  SpecialBuild:     False
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  Language:         Language Neutral
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  OS Name:                   Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  OS Edition:                ServerStandard
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  OSVersion:                 Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  CurrentCulture:            sl-SI
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  Processor Architecture:    AMD64
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  Event Registration Source :    AppFabric_Setup
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : Initiating V1.0 Upgrade module.
2014-03-21 11:02:34, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : V1.0 is not installed.
2014-03-21 11:02:54, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : Initiating V1 Upgrade pre-install.
2014-03-21 11:02:54, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : V1.0 is not installed, not taking backup.
2014-03-21 11:02:55, Information           Setup  Executing C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe with commandline -iru.
2014-03-21 11:02:55, Information           Setup  Return code from aspnet_regiis.exe is 0
2014-03-21 11:02:55, Information           Setup  Process.Start: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /quiet /norestart /i "c:\6c4006b0b3f6dee1bf616f1967\Microsoft CCR and DSS Runtime 2008 R3.msi" /l*vx "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2014-03-21 11-02-55).log"
2014-03-21 11:02:57, Information           Setup  Process.ExitCode: 0x00000000
2014-03-21 11:02:57, Information           Setup  Windows features successfully enabled.
2014-03-21 11:02:57, Information           Setup  Process.Start: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /quiet /norestart /i "c:\6c4006b0b3f6dee1bf616f1967\Packages\AppFabric-1.1-for-Windows-Server-64.msi" ADDDEFAULT=Worker,WorkerAdmin,CacheService,CacheAdmin,Setup /l*vx "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2014-03-21 11-02-57).log" LOGFILE="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2014-03-21 11-02-57).log" INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server" LANGID=en-US
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup  Process.ExitCode: 0x00000643
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Error                 Setup  AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Error                 Setup  
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Error                 Setup  AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Error                 Setup  
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Core.SetupException: AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.WindowsInstallerProxy.GenerateAndThrowSetupException(Int32 exitCode, LogEventSource logEventSource)
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.WindowsInstallerProxy.Invoke(LogEventSource logEventSource, InstallMode installMode, String packageIdentity, List`1 updateList, List`1 customArguments)
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.MsiInstaller.InstallSelectedFeatures()
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.MsiInstaller.Install()
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Client.ProgressPage.StartAction()
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup  
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup  === Summary of Actions ===
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup  Required Windows components   :  Completed Successfully
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup  IIS Management Console            :  Completed Successfully
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup  Microsoft CCR and DSS Runtime 2008 R3         :  Completed Successfully
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup  AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server  :  Failed
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup  Hosting Services          :  Failed
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup  Caching Services          :  Failed
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup  Hosting Administration            :  Failed
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup  Cache Administration          :  Failed
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup  Microsoft Update  :  Skipped
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup  Microsoft Update          :  Skipped
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup  
2014-03-21 11:03:45, Information           Setup  ===== Logging stopped: 2014-03-21 11:03:45+01:00 =====
```

I have tried this solution but no success:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205927/appfabric-installation-failed-because-installer-msi-returned-with-error-code-1

My system enviroment variable `PSModulesPath` has this value: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`

I have also followed this link with no success:
http://jefferytay.wordpress.com/2013/12/11/installing-appfabric-on-windows-server-2012/

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolution:

Deleted the groups AS_Observers and AS_Administrators (if they are there), and then installation succeeded.

Good day.

Comment: This was awesome.  I found so many links to deleting the " in the environment variable(which did not work).  I did this and it installed like a champ!

Answer (score 0):

I have done all that is above this and I am still having this issue. Any ideas?

```
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  ===== Logging started: 2022-10-08 22:06:58-05:00 =====
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  File:             c:\fb5c864807f3b573705b6423\setup.exe
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  InternalName:     Setup.exe
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  OriginalFilename: Setup.exe
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  FileVersion:      1.1.2106.32
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  FileDescription:  Setup.exe
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  Product:          Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server AppFabric
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  ProductVersion:   1.1.2106.32
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  Debug:            False
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  Patched:          False
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  PreRelease:       False
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  PrivateBuild:     False
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  SpecialBuild:     False
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  Language:         Language Neutral
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  OS Name:                   Windows Server 2022 Standard
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  OS Edition:                ServerStandard
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  OSVersion:                 Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  CurrentCulture:            en-US
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  Processor Architecture:    AMD64
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  Event Registration Source :    AppFabric_Setup
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : Initiating V1.0 Upgrade module.
2022-10-08 22:06:58, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : V1.0 is not installed.
2022-10-08 22:07:06, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : Initiating V1 Upgrade pre-install.
2022-10-08 22:07:06, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Upgrade.V1UpgradeSetupModule : V1.0 is not installed, not taking backup.
2022-10-08 22:07:06, Information           Setup  Executing C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe with commandline -iru.
2022-10-08 22:07:06, Information           Setup  Return code from aspnet_regiis.exe is 0
2022-10-08 22:07:06, Information           Setup  Windows features successfully enabled.
2022-10-08 22:07:06, Information           Setup  Process.Start: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /quiet /norestart /i "c:\fb5c864807f3b573705b6423\Packages\AppFabric-1.1-for-Windows-Server-64.msi" ADDDEFAULT=Worker,WorkerAdmin,CacheClient,Setup /l*vx "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1(2022-10-08 22-07-06).log" LOGFILE="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\AppServerSetup1_1_CustomActions(2022-10-08 22-07-06).log" INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server" LANGID=en-US
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup  Process.ExitCode: 0x00000643
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Error                 Setup  AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Error                 Setup  
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Error                 Setup  AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Error                 Setup  
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup  Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Core.SetupException: AppFabric installation failed because installer MSI returned with error code : 1603
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.WindowsInstallerProxy.GenerateAndThrowSetupException(Int32 exitCode, LogEventSource logEventSource)
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.WindowsInstallerProxy.Invoke(LogEventSource logEventSource, InstallMode installMode, String packageIdentity, List`1 updateList, List`1 customArguments)
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.MsiInstaller.InstallSelectedFeatures()
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Installer.MsiInstaller.Install()
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Setup.Client.ProgressPage.StartAction()
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup  
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup  === Summary of Actions ===
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup  Required Windows components   :  Completed Successfully
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup  IIS Management Console            :  Completed Successfully
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup  AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server  :  Failed
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup  Hosting Services          :  Failed
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup  Cache Client          :  Failed
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup  Hosting Administration            :  Failed
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup  Microsoft Update  :  Skipped
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup  Microsoft Update          :  Skipped
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup  
2022-10-08 22:07:50, Information           Setup  ===== Logging stopped: 2022-10-08 22:07:50-05:00 =====
```